# Unresolved reference: compose in RelayBaseComposable

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, import, figma

I tried to import figma designs to Android studio using Relay to Figma tool, but it gave me this error after i fixed my HOME_JAVA problem, which it was telling me that HOME_JAVA invalid directory.

this is my code:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
id'com.google.relay'                 //added to figma
```

}

android {
compileSdk 32

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets {
            srcDir('src/main/ui-packages')          //added to figma
        }
    }
}


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.figma_layout"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Unresolved reference: compose in RelayBaseComposable` -- this error message indicates that the code is attempting to access the `compose` function from the `RelayBaseComposable` class, but this class or function cannot be located.

It seems like the **Relay to Figma** tool requires the **Relay library** to be added as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file, but it's not specified in the dependencies block of the code you provided.

Can you try this? Add this to your dependencies block:

```
implementation 'com.google.relay:relay:0.1.0'
```

This should import the **Relay library**, thus resolving the reference to the `compose` function mentioned in your error message.